# Крякозябры в IE при использовании Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer

Вставляю часть контента на сайт с помощью Ajax конструкцией $("#about_us").html(data);

Но в IE9 отображаются крякозябры вида "РќР°С€Рё РїСЂРёРѕСЂРёС‚РµС‚С‹:".

Страница в utf-8 без bom, все страницы на сайте перекодировал в эту кодировку через notepad++.

В самом начале php файла добавил: header("Content-type: text/html;charset=utf-8");

В фале .htaccess добавил строку:
AddDefaultCharset utf-8

Ajax запрос выглядит следующим образом:

```
$.get("/js/about_us.txt", function(data){
    $("#about_us").html(data);
    }, "text");
```

Файл about_us.txt также в кодировке utf-8 без bom
Во всех браузерах отображается нормально, а в IE отображаются крякозябры, причем смена кодировки страницы в браузере вручную ничего не меняет.

Причем, второй файл, который я подключаю через ajax таким же способом отображается нормально, хотя разницы между их кодировками или еще чем-нибудь нет.

Остальной контент на странице тоже правильно отображается, только этот текст, подключенный через Ajax криво.

Пробовал тупо вставлять этот текст из файла в исходный код - все нормально.

Видимо что-то с Ajax...

Как можно решить эту проблему?

```
$.get("/js/about_us.txt", function(data){
    $("#about_us").html(data);
    }, "text");

$.get("/js/etapy.txt", function(data){
    $("#etapy").html(data);
    $("#etapy").hide();
    $(document).ready(function(){$("#shapka_block1").corner("30px")});$(document).ready(function(){$("#shapka_block2").corner("30px")});$(document).ready(function(){$("#shapka_block3").corner("30px")});
    $("#etapy").slideDown("slow");
    }, "text");
```

Адрес сайта, на котором проблема: http://оценить.рф

Comment: Телепатов нет. Нужно больше кода.

Comment: Такое количество раз поднимался тут этот вопрос, что подташнивает. Когда вы регистрировались, вам было выведено сообщение: **"Пользоваться поиском строго запрещается!"**

Comment: Перепробовал все, что только можно, поэтому и написал здесь

Comment: Говорю же, дайте больше кода. А еще лучше - весь.

Comment: Добавил весь код ajax

Comment: В IE8 воспроизвести не смог. Попробуйте прописать кодировку в строке подключения скрипта.

`<script src="/js/ajax.js" charset="utf-8" type="text/javascript"></script>`

Comment: что-то ничего не понимаю, как-то само по себе все решилось... просыпаюсь, а проблемы нет)

Comment: Значит проблема была в кэше...)

Answer (score 1):

Могу предположить что вы отдаёте хиадер:

Content-Type: text/html; charset=**"UTF8"**

так вот, IE не понимает UTF8, нужно писать: **UTF-8**

Comment: Я же написал, что заголовок такой: header("Content-type: text/html;charset=utf-8");
Так что дело не в этом

Comment: Поищите по хешу - поднимали вопрос. кодировочку надо указать у аякс запроса.

Comment: Возможно, но дело в том, что второй ajax запрос выводит все нормально, в нормальной кодировке, хотя разницы между ними нет, может они как-то конфликтуют между собой?